# GASでif (foo != "white") { bar; } とするとfooが白くてもbarが実行される

Tags: google-apps-script

お世話になります。
以下のプログラムは私が初めて書いたGASのプログラムです。
やりたいことは、スプレッドシートで、各行において、一番左のセルの背景色に、その行全体の背景色を合わせるというものです。

```
function colorAsLeft(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var savedColor = "black";
  for (var row = 1; row <= lastrow; row++) { 
    var currColor = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getBackground();
    Logger.log("row=%s", row);
    Logger.log("before savedColor=%s currColor=%s", savedColor, currColor);
    // if (currColor != "white") { # NG
    // if (currColor != "#FFFFFF") { # NG
    if (currColor != "#ffffff") { #OK
      savedColor = currColor;
      Logger.log("in if savedColor=%s currColor=%s", savedColor, currColor);
    }
    Logger.log("savedColor=%s currColor=%s", savedColor, currColor);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastcol).setBackground(savedColor);
  }
}
```

上のようにすると、if文でcurrColor（現在行の先頭セルの色）を"#ffffff"と比較するとうまくいく（currColorが白でないときのみifブロックに入る）が、"white"や"#FFFFFF"と比較するとうまくいきません（必ずブロックに入ります。）。
なぜでしょうか。
私としては読みやすい"white"にしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「何故なのか」に対しては、ドキュメントの [getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) によれば、返り値がカラーコードと規定されているから、だと思います。

Comment: この辺を参考に自分で変換してみるとか。[Get color name by HEX or RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9224404/9014308), [Name that Color.](http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/), [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1573053/9014308), [Convert RGB to ColorName String Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5486730/9014308), [Color Schemes and palettes - Desktop Liberation](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/colorfiesta/colorpalettes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APIの結果がどんな形式なのかはAPIを提供する側(この場合はGoogle)が決めることなので、質問者さんが`"white"`がいいと思ってもどうしようもありません。結果の形式を指定するAPIもないようですし。

こういった場合にコードの可読性を改善するには、定数のシンボルを用意するのが普通です。

```
const WHITE = "#ffffff";
...
    if (currColor != WHITE) {
      ...
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。文字列を返す以上仕方ないですね。改善法も含めて納得です！